# I want to travel to the USA as a tourist while I'm employed by a US employer

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I recently applied for a B1/B2 visa because I want to visit the US for 20 days for tourism. The only thing that concerns me is my current employment with the US based employer.

I'm doing remote work for the US company and I have a 2-year contract with them. They also sent me a letter which confirms that I'm an employee of that company. What I want to know is if I would be able to get a B1/B2 visa issued given the before-mentioned condition.

P.S. I did have a valid 3-year B1/B2 visa which expired last year.

Comment: The fact that you work for a US based company shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: B1/B2 is a combined tourism/business visa. Are you worried they won't accept your application as a business visa? Are you worried they might think you'll be doing paid work?

Comment: I am going to US for tourism purposes. I am worried they might think I'll be doing paid work there, which I technically can since I am an employee of a US based company.

Comment: OK I took the liberty of rewording your question very slightly based on your comments - I hope I didn't change the meaning at all.

Comment: Nope. It's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as requirements for your [B1/B2 visa are concerned](http://travel.state.gov/visa/temp/types/types_1262.html) the source of your income is irrelevant as long as it is legal, so you should not have an issue obtaining B1/B2 visa as long as necessary conditions are satisfied.

As far as employment is concerned you are [obviously ineligible to work for you US employer](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/information-employers-employees/information-employers-and-employees) while in the United States since your employer has to provide for you employment authorization which would be a different type of visa.

One thing to note that if you mention that you intend to visit your employer during your visit you will likely get a denial since it might be construed as intent to work in the US though again this is in the discretion of the consulate employees.

Comment: what if the primary intent is to visit US client (employer)? does B1 visa allows that?

Comment: A B1 visa will allow you to *visit* your employer, but not to do work while you visit. However the definition of *work* is quite narrow. Meetings, planning, discussion etc. are all allowed. We have other questions on the difference.